# Need to split the xml tag values by 10 tag item in one fie and another 10 tag item in another file using python

Tags: python, xml, split, elementtree

I am having the simple xml file, need to split the first 10 tags value in one file and another 10 tags value in another text for all the value each 10 value in separate text file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Invoice.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for e in root.iter('LineItem'):
    print (e.text)
```

Here is my current output, first 10 values in one file and from 11 to 20 in another file.like wise 21 to 30 etc..

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21

Answer (score 0):

You can either add all the items to a list and then process them in batches of ten, or you can keep track of the element number and change the output file on every tenth element.

Batching

```py
l = [e for e in root.iter('LineItem')]
num_batches = math.ceil(len(l)/10)
for batch in range(num_batches):
    # Setup output file
    for e in l[batch*10 : min((batch+1)*10, len(l) - 1)]:  # Iterate over each element in batch
        print(e.text)
```

Element Counting

```py
i = 0
for e in root.iter('LineItem'): 
    if i % 10 == 0:
        # Change output file
    i+=1
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: Getting error -- 
for batch in range(num_batches):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Oh change the second line to this `num_batches = int(len(l) / 10) + (1 if len(l) % 10 else 0)`. `math.ceil(len(l)/10)` will also work and it's a bit more concise.

Comment: After the cahnge getting error -     num_batches = int(len(l) / 10) + (1 if len(l) % 10 else 0). math.ceil(len(l)/10)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'math'

Comment: @JordanG: it looks like you have posted untested code. And you never show how to actually create the output files.

Comment: Element counting format is working but 21th element is not printing, Printing 1-10 and 11-20, 21th elemnt i snot printing

Comment: @mzjn The examples were meant to be more pseudo code as I don't know what the exact application is. @balaji balehead The `int(len(l) / 10) + (1 if len(l) % 10 else 0)` and `math.ceil(len(l)/10) ` examples are two separate ways of computing the number of batches. Don't put them both on the same line.

Comment: @balaji balehead can you post the code you are using for the element counting?